# Assertion failed on __pthread_mutex_cond_lock_full in a load test

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, debian, mutex

I used the following code to create a timer object in my c++ application running on a debian 8.

```
class Timer
{
private:
    std::condition_variable cond_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    int duration;
    void *params;

public:
    Timer::Timer(void (*func)(void*))
    {
      this->handler = func;
      this->duration = 0;
      this->params = NULL;
    };

    Timer::~Timer(){};

    void Timer::start(int duree, void* handlerParams)
    {
      this->duration = duree;
      this->params   = handlerParams;
      /*
       * Launch the timer thread and wait it
       */
      std::thread([this]{
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
                std::cv_status ret = cond_.wait_for(mlock, 
                                     std::chrono::seconds(duration));
                if ( ret ==  std::cv_status::timeout )  
                {
                    handler(params);
                }
              }).detach();

      };

      void Timer::stop()
      {
          cond_.notify_all();
      }
    };
```

It works correctly under gdb and under normal conditions, but in a load test of 30 requests or more, it crashes with the assertion :

nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:350: __pthread_mutex_cond_lock_full: Assertion `(-(e)) != 3 || !robust' failed.

I don't understand the cause of this assertion. Can anyone help me please ??
Thank you

Comment: This is the gdb backtrace result : #0  0xb7fdcd40 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7621367 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#2  0xb7622a23 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#3  0xb761a6c7 in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0xb7756af4 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=assertion@entry=0xb7c907f5 "(-(e)) != 3 || !robust",file=file@entry=0xb7c907d8 "../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c", line=line@entry=350,
    function=function@entry=0xb7c90c9c <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.8302> "__pthread_mutex_cond_lock_full") at assert.c:92

Comment: #4  0xb761a777 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=assertion@entry=0xb7c907f5 "(-(e)) != 3 || !robust", file=file@entry=0xb7c907d8 "../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c",
    line=line@entry=350, function=function@entry=0xb7c90c9c <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.8302> "__pthread_mutex_cond_lock_full") at assert.c:101
#5  0xb7c84427 in __pthread_mutex_cond_lock_full (mutex=0x7ff2e978) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:350
#6  0xb7c8a102 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:360

Comment: #6  0xb7c8a102 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:360
#7  0x080c99a2 in __gthread_cond_timedwait (__abs_timeout=0x662e02c8, __mutex=0x7ff2e978, __cond=0x7ff2e948) at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/gthr-default.h:871
#8  __wait_until_impl<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > > (__atime=..., __lock=<synthetic pointer>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/condition_variable:165

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a detached thread that accesses the timer object, so it's likely that you destroyed the Timer object but the thread is still running and accessing it's member(mutex, conditional variable).

The assert itself says, from glibc source code, that the owner of the mutex has died.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your comments ! I'll try to change the thread detach, and do the load tests.
This is a MVCE of my problem, which is a part of a huge application.

```
/**
 * \file Timer.hxx
 * \brief Definition of Timer class.
 */
  #include <chrono>
  #include <thread>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <condition_variable>

    class Timer
    {
    private:
    std::condition_variable cond_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    int duration;
    void *params;

    public:
    Timer(void (*func)(void*));
    ~Timer();

    void (*handler)(void*);
    void start(int duree, void* handlerParams);
    void stop();
    };

 /*
 * Timer.cxx
 */
 #include "Timer.hxx"
 Timer::Timer(void (*func)(void*))
{
//this->set_handler(func, params);
this->handler = func;
this->duration = 0;
this->params = NULL;
}

Timer::~Timer()
{
}

void Timer::start(int duree, void* handlerParams)
{
this->duration = duree;
this->params   = handlerParams;
/*
 * Launch the timer thread and wait it
 */
std::thread([this]{
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
                std::cv_status ret = cond_.wait_for(mlock, std::chrono::seconds(duration));
                if ( ret ==  std::cv_status::timeout )  
                {
                    handler(params);
                }
              }).detach();

   }


 void Timer::stop()
 {
  cond_.notify_all();
 }

/*
 * MAIN
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "Timer.hxx"

using namespace std;

void timeoutHandler(void* params)
{
char* data= (char*)params;
cout << "Timeout triggered !! Received data is: " ;
if (data!=NULL)
    cout << data << endl;   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int delay=5;
char data[20] ="This is a test" ;

Timer *t= new Timer(&timeoutHandler) ;
t->start(delay, data);
cout << "Timer started !! " << endl;    
sleep(1000);
t->stop();
delete t;
cout << "Timer deleted !! " << endl;    

return 0;
}
```